# Prevent `using static` Directive with RequireQualifiedAccess

Tags: c#, .net, f#

In F#, there is a .NET attribute that prevents programmers to use `using static`:

> Adding the `[<RequireQualifiedAccess>]` attribute to a module indicates that the module may not be opened and that references to the elements of the module require explicit qualified access. For example, the Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.List module has this attribute.
>
> This is useful when functions and values in the module have names that are likely to conflict with names in other modules and requiring qualified access can greatly increase the long-term maintainability and evolvability of a library: functions can be added to the module without breaking source compatibility.

Is there any attribute equivalent to `RequireQualifiedAccess` in C#? I'd like to have the following code throw compile errors:

```
using static System.Math;

[RequireQualifiedAccess]
public class Circle
{
    public Circle(double radius)
    {
        Radius = radius;
    }

    public double Radius { get; private set; }

    public double Area => PI * Pow(Radius, 2);
}
```

Comment: Even if there were - I doubt it will prevent what you want, because for that, "Math" should be marked with that attribute, not `Circle` (as far as I understand description of that attribute).

Comment: @Evk Yes, I want an equivalent attribute inside `Math` class.

Comment: I mean even if there were such thing for C# (and I don't think there is) - you won't be able to mark external class (`Math`) with it anyway.